# Switching branches along with moving committed but unpushed commits

Tags: git

I read few threads about this, but need some clarifications. I see I can get the unpushed commit in my local branch with

```
    git log origin/master..HEAD
```

When I moving from one branch to another, is there a way to automatically apply the unpushed commits (even if we have to resolve merge conflicts, if any) onto the moved to branch?

Also, on my local branch, when I have uncommited changes, and I checkout a different branch, uncommitted changes get moved to the moved-to branch, However git documentation says this should throw an error. Is this set somewhere in the config? Why am I not seeing the error?

```
 $ git checkout mytopic
 error: You have local changes to 'frotz'; not switching branches.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I moving from one branch to another, is there a way to automatically apply the unpushed commits (even if we have to resolve merge conflicts, if any) onto the moved to branch?

If you want to **move** the commits to another branch then you can use `git rebase`. Otherwise, you most likely want to simply `git merge` the first branch with another branch.

> Also, on my local branch, when I have uncommited changes, and I checkout a different branch, uncommitted changes get moved to the moved-to branch, However git documentation says this should throw an error. Is this set somewhere in the config? Why am I not seeing the error?

This depends on what local changes were made and what changes are in the branch you are moving to. If there are merge conflicts, then you will get an error. If there are no merge conflicts, then you can checkout the branch without any error.

Answer (score 1):

There is no automatic way to apply unpushed commits.  You can do it manually using

```
git rebase --onto
```

Depending on what you are trying to accomplish you may need to create a temporary branch or do some fast forward merge operations as well.  It depends on whether you want to keep both copies of the commits or not.

For your second question - I don't personally like that `git checkout` operates that way, but I believe it will complain if the files you have modified have changes on the branch you are switching to.  Otherwise it doesn't say anything.